# How can I download multiple jpeg files from an url in R?

Tags: r, image, loops, url, satellite-image

I need to download multiple .jpg files that has "*b13" in filename in the url below. Can anyone help me how to list the file names and download them in a folder?
https://www.data.jma.go.jp/mscweb/data/himawari/list_ha2.html

```
install.packages("jpeg")
library(jpeg)
install.packages("here")
library(here)
myurl <- "https://www.data.jma.go.jp/mscweb/data/himawari/list_ha2.html"
for (i in 1:138) { 
myurl <- paste(myurl[i,1], sep = "")
z <- tempfile()
download.file(myurl,z,mode="wb")
pic <- readJPEG(z)
writeJPEG(pic,here("Q:\\R_himawari"), paste("image", "i", ".jpg") 
          file.remove(z)
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) CSS selector to select the `href` of interest by the substring "b13". The `[href*=b13]` targets `href` attributes containing the characters "b13". Use `url_absolute()` to complete the paths to the source image files. Then download those files. `i` can come from the loop and should not be a hard-coded string/character "i".

```
install.packages("jpeg")
library(jpeg)
install.packages("here")
#library(here)
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)


myurl <- "https://www.data.jma.go.jp/mscweb/data/himawari/list_ha2.html"

links <- read_html(myurl) %>%
  html_elements("table [href*=b13]") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  url_absolute(myurl)

for (i in seq_along(links)) {
  z <- tempfile()
  download.file(links[i], z, mode = "wb")
  pic <- readJPEG(z)
  # writeJPEG(pic, paste0(Q:/R_himawari/", "image_", i, ".jpg")
  writeJPEG(pic, paste0("C:/Users/User/DestinationFolder", "/image_", i, ".jpg"))
  file.remove(z)
}
```